# Windows Phone WPF override progressbar color only on one page

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

Is there a way to override the color of a progressbar only on one page.

I found the solution for all pages via ApplicationResources

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
       <x:String x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush">White</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

EDIT:
I have this in MainPage.xaml but it has no effect

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <x:String x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush">White</x:String>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

My project is a Windows Phone 8.1 Application, it's not a Silverlight one, not sure if this has an impact.

EDIT 2: Adding this at the application level is working:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <x:String x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush">White</x:String>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Is there a way to have theme override working at page level?

Comment: Declare the resource under `Page.Resources` with the same name and different value to override application resource.

Comment: @RohitVats am I missing something? It doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Place you change in the resource of the page of interest...

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ...>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <x:String x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush">White</x:String>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    ...
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

When looking up a resource it checks the page before the application level resources.